# How can we add text in all row of spinner item

Tags: android, android-spinner

I want to implement one spinner which represent the weight between 40 to 
        141 kg so I used for loop and now I want each Item of spinner comes in 
        item with kg(40kg, 41kg, 43kg...)form

```
    ArrayList<String> w = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (int i = 41; i <= 140; i++) {
        w.add(Integer.toString(i));
    }
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapterWieght = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, 
    android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, w);
    spinWeight.setAdapter(adapterWieght);
    spinWeight.setOnItemSelectedListener(new 
    AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
      @Override
      public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, 
      int pos, long l) {
         final String str_weight =
          adapterView.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString().trim();
        }
        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {
        }
    });
```

Comment: you can add kg at the time of add int value like :  w.add(Integer.toString(i)+"Kg");

Comment: Thank you @Yogesh, now I want only integer value will store on server kg will not store so what can I do for that

Answer (score 1):

In your for loop:

```
//...
    for (int i = 41; i <= 140; i++) {
        w.add(i + "kg");
    }
//...
```

Also, probably fix that typo `adapterWieght` to `adapterWeight` for better naming.

In your onItemSelected :

```
//...
    String temp = adapterView.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString().trim();
    final String str_weight= temp.replaceAll("[^0-9]", "");
//...
```

Comment: Thank you @Ray it is working but now I want to store only integer value on server not to store kg.

Comment: Thank you sir this is which I want

Comment: Suppose that in our spinner I will use select weight on first row and I will click on button then select weight will not store on server, so what should I do for that?